# Why does removeChild() prevent me from doing appendChild() within a Javascript Function?

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

In this code when I call the cleanGrid() function my goal was to get rid of the div that was class 'circle' and to replace it with a div with class 'square'. For what I'm really using this code for they are not replacable items so replaceChild() would not work. If I comment out the function call to cleanGrid() the code runs fine and the button just adds a div with class 'square' for each click. What I want to actually happen is for cleanGrid() to remove whatever is in the 'grid' div and leave room for whatever should be added after this function is called--but nothing can be added after this function is called and I'm not sure why.

```
<body>
<div id="grid"><div class="circle">hello</div></div>
<button onclick="addSquare()">add a Square</button>

<script language="JavaScript">
var g = {};
g.myGrid = document.getElementById("grid");

function addSquare() {

 // Calling cleanGrid() is giving me problems.
 // I want to wipe everything clean first and then add the divs of the 'square' class.
 // But instead it just clears the 'grid' div and doesn't allow anything to be added.
 cleanGrid();  // WHY NOT?

 var newSquare = document.createElement("div");
 newSquare.className = "square";
 newSquare.innerHTML = "square";
 g.myGrid.appendChild(newSquare);
}

function cleanGrid() {
 var x = document.getElementById("grid");
 while(x.childNodes) {
  var o = x.lastChild;
  x.removeChild(o);
 }
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your `cleanGrid` function will work quite the way you've coded it. `x.childNodes` will continue to be truthy even if it's empty (an empty `NodeList` isn't falsey). So I suspect it's throwing an exception (on the `removeChild` call) or endlessly looping, which (either way) is why other code isn't running. Try running it in a debugging environment (Firefox+Firebug, IE + Visual Studio or the dev toolkit, whatever) where you can see what's going on.

Here's an off-the-cuff reworking of `cleanGrid`:

```
function cleanGrid() {
  var x = document.getElementById("grid");
  while (x.lastChild) {
    x.removeChild(x.lastChild);
  }
}
```

Or, of course:

```
function cleanGrid() {
  document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = "";
}
```

...since `innerHTML`, though not standard, is supported by all of the major browsers and most of the minor ones.

Answer (score 0):

T.J. Crowder nailed it down with the logic behind the behavior

However, this will work:

```
function cleanGrid() {
 var x = document.getElementById("grid");
 var len =x.childNodes.length;
 while(len) {
  x.removeChild(x.lastChild);
 --len;
 }
}
```